# Ubuntu and windows boot issue

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu, just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, I installed it in same hard drive (1 TB) in which i had installed windows but in a different partition, each has 500gb of space...but now am not able to boot windows, I actually want to use both...so can some one help me out with it on how to use both windows and Ubuntu (ext4, / is the partition format)...thanks

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu, and when you are in press `Ctr+Alt+T` key combination or 'Dash - Terminal' to open a terminal emulator window, and run this command:

      **sudo update-grub**

You should see a list of lines listed in there, and your Windows system should be present too. Then you can reboot, and try to boot into Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your Grub loader seems to be silent, tru updating it
"sudo update-grub"  in a terminal session, it should make a windows entry.